# Problem when installing pybox2d with anaconda

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to install pybox2d through anaconda navigator with Python 3.7 , but it shows this error, I could not solve

I read all the library [documentation](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/wiki/manual)!

Error:

(user) user@euser:~$ conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/kne pybox2d
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - jeepney
  - notebook==5.7.4
  - pybox2d
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My tensorflow and pybox2d where conflicting.

I followed these steps by anuj:

```
conda create -n stackoverflow_env python=3.7
source activate stackoverflow_env
conda install -c kne pybox2d
```

and then installed tensorflow from anaconda navigator in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new conda environment to avoid being influenced by the existing installations and followed the steps given below. After this, Box2D is importing fine for me.

```
conda create -n stackoverflow_env python=3.7
source activate stackoverflow_env
conda install -c kne pybox2d
```